# Why does my loop only produce results after I manually stop the command? For loop optimization

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Sep_1991 is a 3D array, with a size (240,296,296). I have a for loop to set values greater than 0.000999984 and 0.000999985 as 'not a number' and then set them to one, so I have an array of blanks (masked) and ones. I then take the mean of the first axis so that I finish with an array that is size (296,296).

```
for i in Sep_1991:
    Sep_1991[(Sep_1991 >= 0.000999984) & (Sep_1991 <= 0.000999985)]= np.nan
    Sep_1991[np.isnan(Sep_1991)]=1
    mask_1991=Sep_1991.astype(int)

mean_mask_1991 = mask_1991.mean(axis= -3)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to optimize my for loop. As of now it runs forever but if I hit the "stop the current command" button I get a keyboard interrupt error (expected), BUT my array appears with all the correct numbers. What makes it so that it runs forever and why does my array/variable appear regardless after I manually end the running?

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

edit: I ran this code the other day (nearly identical) and the run time was quite fast ... I don't know what I have changed for it to have become so slow

Comment: looks like you are doing the same 3 tasks inside the for-loop for every value of `i`. So what is the use of a `for-loop` here?

Comment: Normally we use the `i` iteration variable in the loop.  Here you just do the same thing 240 times (the 1st dim).  It looks like you skipped the early chapters of the Intro to python book.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an infinite loop -- it's merely much longer than you care to wait.  Your 3D array has roughly 21 million cells.  For *each* cell (`for` statement), you reassign the *entire* array (loop body),

```
for i in Sep_1991:
    Sep_1991[(Sep_1991 >= 0.000999984) & (Sep_1991 <= 0.000999985)]= np.nan
```

This is an **O(N^2)** algorithm, with N~= 21 million, on the order of 10^15 operations.

I suspect that you need to get rid of the loop, and simply use the appropriate vectorized operations.